# In PHP, is there an alternative to putting @ in front of functions whose variables are defined later? Explanation + code inside

Tags: php

I'd like to preface this by saying that I've read answers to similar questions, and haven't managed to find something that both does the job and does not slow the site down.

I have a site that displays messages based on users' choices and actions. The code might look something like this :

```
if (option 1) {
    $message1 = "Message A";
}
else if (option 2){
    $message1 = "Message B";
}
else {
    $message1 = "Message C";
}
```

There are a hand full of these throughout the site. When i want to echo the messages somewhere within the html structure i have to write:

```
<?php
    if (isset($message1)) {
       echo $message1;
    }
?>
```

I've written a simple function which does its job:

```
function message($msg){
    if (isset($msg)) {
        echo $msg;
    }
}
```

The problem is that i get notices for undefined variables, which makes sense because the variable isn't defined before the user clicks a button. I would like to avoid turning off error reporting.

So, is adding @ in front of the function the only way? The code would then look like:

```
<?php
@message($message1);
?>
```

If that is acceptable, then great. If not, I'm open to alternatives.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'slowing the site down'? What's the actual problem you're having, values not returning values? Just initialize their return value properly so you always have something to work with.

Comment: I'm defining the messages based on users' responses. So for example if i have a registration form, if they put 2 different passwords and hit submit, they get a message saying that the passwords don't match. If they input every field correctly they get a "registration successful" message etc This is all done in php because it is a course project, so no javascript is included. The message variable gets populated only when users click the button, it is undefined beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, your use-case seems to make sense. In that case I would have an array with all error messages, something like:

```
$messages = array();
...
$messages['registration-form']['error']['password-mismatch'] = 'Passwords do not match';
...
```

And when I validate the input and find mismatching passwords, I would do:

```
// at the top
$errors = array();
...
// passwords don't match
$errors['passwords-mismatch'] = $messages['registration-form']['error']['password-mismatch'];
```

And where I output the form below the passwords:

```
messages($errors, 'password-mismatch');
```

And finally the function would be something like:

```
function messages($errors, $error) {
  if (isset($errors[$error])) {
    // I would wrap it in a span to highlight the error
    echo '<span class="error">' . $errors[$error] . '</span>';
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I understand the logic behind your suggestion. it does seem like a more roundabout way to do it, but a sound one. Thank you.

Comment: @PHP_newb001 I make a lot of multi-language sites, so having everything organized from the start similar to this makes multiple languages and feature additions a breeze. But I would do it the same for a single language, I don't like mixing texts / content with logic and like I said, adding a form field when it is set up like this, is easy.

Comment: Yeah, I think I get it. Just need more experience under my belt I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable by reference, `function message(&$msg){`, no  error will be raise.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php):

> If you assign, pass, or return an undefined variable by reference, it will get created.

Comment: Strangely enough this works. However, you're just hiding the problem instead of solving it so in that sense it is not any better than using `@` IMO.

Comment: I merely answered to OP's question. But as always "it can be done" does not mean "you should do it". Personally, I strongly discourage this  approach

Comment: I know, I was just giving my opinion :-)

Answer (score -4):

Try this php in built function:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: or set error_roperting in your php script like below:
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

Comment: *I would like to avoid turning off error reporting.*.

Comment: Supressing warnings, errors and notices doesn't mean that you've fixed any problems.